# trouble with sending data from html-form

Tags: html

User has html-form, then user fills all field and data transferred to PHP script.
How do would data send, but not refresh html page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want the page to be refreshed and submit data, you will have to use the **ajax** for that, have a look at its tutorial at **[w3school.com](http://www.w3schools.com/Ajax/Default.Asp)**

Comment: thank, I just thought that this problem is solved without AJAX
PS thank for link

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like an AJAX solution.
[Quick google search](http://www.ajaxprojects.com/ajax/tutorialdetails.php?itemid=219)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to send the data **without** refreshing the page, you'll want to do an [ajax submit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_(programming)).  The easiest way to do this is via
the [jQuery AJAX Library](http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/).  A quick example could be:

```
//example from the jQuery API docs.
$.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: "some.php",
   data: $("#form_to_submit").serialize(),
   success: function(msg){
     alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
   }
 });
```

Comment: thank, but I not fully understood, can You write simple html-form with such use jQuery?

Comment: You would use jQuery to handle the submitting of a form.  Just google for "ajax form submit jquery" and you'll find a decent example or two.